# read FormData object on server-side ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, form-data

I am sending an AJAX request having the "data" property being a FormData with a single key something like this:

```
var fData = new FormData($(accRegForm));
fData.append("Name", "Test Test");

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(fData),
    url: "/DataService.ashx",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false
});
```

Now on the server, how can I retrieve the vale of "Name" inside ASP.NET?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {

    string name = context.Request.QueryString["Name"];
    // ..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a POST request, I was able to read the FormData collection on server using the following :

```
Request.Form["Name"]
```

In other words, the FormData key/value pair are sent through the normal/usual request payload. In case of POST request, you can use Request.Form and in case of GET request, you can use Request.QueryString instead.

HTH,
Regards